# String to latlng and setCenter/marker problems. [GMaps-API-3]

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm new to javascript and Google Maps API. I'm trying to create a set of functions which:

1-Get and address and return latlng as a string so I can store it in a database for later use

2-Get the string from the database or directly from the function 1 to centralize the map and set a marker.

Here is the progress I made so far:

```
var map;
var geocode;
function initializeMap(lat, lng){
var eventLatlng=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
var mapOptions={
zoom: 13,
center: eventLatlng,
mapTypeId:  google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}

function getLocation(){
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({'address':address}, function(results,status){
    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
        var res = results[0].geometry.location;
        return res.toString();
    }else{
        alert("Geocoding failed:"+status)
    }
});
}

function setPlace(codeString){
var laln = stringToLatLng(codeString);
map.setCenter(laln);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position:laln});
}

function doAll(){
var test = getLocation();
setPlace(test);
}


function stringToLatLng(rcv){
var input = rcv.substring(1, rcv.length-1);
var latlngStr = input.split(",",2);
alert(latlngStr);
var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]); 
latlngArray[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
return latlngArray[i];
}
```

A good part of this code was taken from official tutorial and even Stackoverflow. InitialiuzeMap works fine. getLocation() also seens to be working. The problem probably is at setPlace() and/or stringToLatLng().

What I already tried:

1-Return getLocation directly [without .toString()] into setPlace - nothing happened.

2-When I put the value returned from getLocation() WITH toString() into stringToLatLng, it says length was undefined. Maybe getLocation is not returning a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you converting to string?

```
results[0].geometry.location
```

contains the geocoded latitude,longitude value as a LatLng object, not as a formatted string.

This can be used eg.

```
res.lat() and res.lng()
```

give you the coordinates you require for database insertion ie

```
var mydbUrl = 'mydb.php?lat='+res.lat()+'&lng='+res.lng();
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

toUrlValue(precision?:number)   string
Returns a string of the form "lat,lng" for this LatLng. We round the lat/lng values to 6 decimal places by default.